# Launching python script and get the result in stout in php

Tags: php, popen

I have a python script `abc.py` that prints out "ABC".
When I tried to launch this script to get the printed result in  php with this code

```
<?php
    $cmd = "/usr/bin/python abc.py";
    $handle = popen($cmd, 'r');
    $res = fread($handle, 8192);
    pclose($handle);

    # Now you can make pretty printer about it.
    return $res;
?>
```

The `$res` is empty. 
And with `$cmd = "/usr/bin/python abc.py 2>&1";`, I got  this error message `/usr/bin/python: can't open file 'abc.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

What's wrong with this? I got same error even when I make the file abc.py accessible to everyone.

Comment: i guess your apache does not have priviledges on abc.py, also you should try using an absolute path to abc.py

Comment: Yep, you'll need to alter the permissions to `abc.py` so that the web server can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I used absolute path for python script, and changed the permission flags so that others can access, but nothing worked. I just copied the python scripts where the php scrips are located, and it works fine. I don't think this is the best way, though.